# jquery ui menu, queue or propagation?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a jquery menu to manipulate elements on DOM.
My menu behaves just the way I need it to, however, if I hover the content area multiple times quickly, my code does not have the time to complete its task and I end up with multiple wraps (or multiple divs that wraps) around my content area. I use a wrap so I can position absolute my menu inside.

I have tried e.stopPropagation(); but that did not work, maybe it's something to do with queue? anyone could give me some pointers please?

I have created a demo to show the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/michelm/rnB2b/1/

```
$('.content').hover(function() {

                $(this).prepend('<div class="menu">Menu</div>').wrap('<div class="mywrap"></div>');
                $(".menu", this).delay(200).fadeIn("fast");

            }, function() {



                $(".menu", this).stop(true).delay(1000).fadeOut(300, function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                     $(this).parent().unwrap();

                });

                $(this).stop(true).delay(1500).fadeIn(300, function() {
                    $(this).unwrap();

                });


            });
```

Comment: What browser support do you need?

Comment: None, really, as long as it works in Chrome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try check if your element is already wrapped and if so not add the wrapper again.

Code:

```
    $('.content').hover(function () {

        if (!$(this).parent().hasClass("mywrap")) {
            $(this).prepend('<div class="menu">Menu</div>').wrap('<div class="mywrap"></div>');
        }
        $(".menu", this).stop().delay(200).fadeIn("fast");

    }, function () {



        $(".menu", this).stop(true).delay(1000).fadeOut(300, function () {
            $(this).remove();
            $(this).parent().unwrap();

        });

        $(this).stop(true).delay(1500).fadeIn(300, function () {
            $(this).unwrap();

        });


    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/YyXd5/

Alternatively you can use css hover like:

```
.content:hover{
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/YyXd5/1/